# Vue.js Composition API vs Options API - posts ref in a v-for loop

Tags: vue.js, ref, vue-composition-api

I'm still new to `VueJS`, and I cannot figure this one out.

I have a page that loads with `axios` from `wordpress` my `posts`:

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      postsUrl: "https://localhost/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/news",

      posts: [] as any[],
      isLoading: false,
      regex: /(<([^>]+)>)/gi,
      errorCaught: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    getPosts() {
      this.isLoading = true;
      axios
        .get(this.postsUrl, { params: { _embed: true } })
        .then((response) => {
          this.posts = response.data;
          console.log("Pages retrieved!");
          console.log(this.posts);
          this.isLoading = false;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
          if (error) {
            this.isLoading = false;
            setTimeout(() => {
              this.errorCaught = true;
            }, 1100);
          }
        });
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getPosts();
  },
};
```

and the template

```
<template>
  <div class="news-container">
    <div class="loading">
      <transition name="fadeLoading">
        <div v-if="isLoading">Loading...</div>
      </transition>
      <transition name="fadeLoading">
        <div v-if="errorCaught">There was an error loading news</div>
      </transition>
    </div>
    <ul v-for="(index) in posts"  :key="index" ref="posts">
      <h1>
        <router-link :to="index.slug" tag="div" key="page.id"
          >{{ index.title.rendered }}
        </router-link>
      </h1>
      <img
        v-if="index._embedded['wp:featuredmedia']"
        :src="index._embedded['wp:featuredmedia'][0].source_url"
      />

      <p class="date">{{ index.date }}</p>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>
```

This works fine, no problem with the Options API.

But when I want to convert this to the Composition API, the posts don't appear:

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import axios from "axios";
import { ref } from "vue";
import { onMounted } from "vue";

const postsUrl = "https://localhost/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/news";

var posts = ref([] as any);
const isLoading = ref(false);
const regex = /(<([^>]+)>)/gi;
const errorCaught = ref(false);

const getPosts = () => {
  isLoading.value = true;
  axios
    .get(postsUrl, { params: { _embed: true, page: 1 } })
    .then((response) => {
      posts = response.data;
      console.log("Pages retrieved!");
      console.log(posts);
      isLoading.value = false;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
      if (error) {
        errorCaught.value = true;
      }
    });
};

onMounted(() => {
  getPosts();
});
</script>
```

I suspect there is a misunderstanding on **my** part how refs work, because If I edit the `<template>` (and have npm run dev  running the server), I can see that the `posts` appear.

Could you help me with what am I doing wrong and why?
Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is here

```
posts = response.data;
```

When you use ref you have to use it with value. Change your code to this:

```
posts.value = response.data;
```

It should be working fine. For more detail you should check here:

https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#ref

Comment: Wow, how did I miss that when I used it on `isLoading` and `errorCaught` properly, thx!

On the other hand, now there is an error:
`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'wp:featuredmedia')`
Only the featuredmedia throws this, other divs with dot notations are fine.
Also, this error does not show if I use Options API.

Comment: Oh and to be perfectly clear, even thought there IS this error showing in console, the images DO STILL get loaded fine.